# Extracting time information from a raw dataset in R

Tags: r, extract

I would like to extract `ID`, `item` information and `time` information from an unstructured dataset. Here is my sample dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(Text_1 = c("Scoring", "1 = Incorrect","Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4", "Demo 1: Color Naming","Amarillo","Azul","Verde","Azul",
                            "Demo 1: Errors","Item 1: Color naming","Amarillo","Azul","Verde","Azul",
                            "Item 1: Time in seconds","Item 1: Errors",
                            "Item 2: Shape Naming","Cuadrado/Cuadro","Cuadrado/Cuadro","Círculo","Estrella","Círculo","Triángulo",
                            "Item 2: Time in seconds","Item 2: Errors"),
                  School.2 = c("Teacher:","DC Name:","Date (mm/dd/yyyy):","Child Grade:","Student Study ID:",NA, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                             0,"1 = Incorrect responses",0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,"1 = Incorrect responses",0,NA,NA,1,1,0,NA,0),
                 X_Elementary_School..3 = c("Bill:","X District","10/7/21","K","123-2222-2:",NA, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                               NA,"Child response",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Child response",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 School.4 = c("Teacher:","DC Name:","Date (mm/dd/yyyy):","Child Grade:","Student Study ID:",NA, 0,NA,1,NA,NA,0,"1 = Incorrect responses",0,1,NA,NA,120,0,"1 = Incorrect responses",NA,1,0,1,NA,1,110,0),
                 Y_Elementary_School..2 = c("John:","X District","11/7/21","K","112-1111-3:",NA, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Child response",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Child response",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, NA,NA))


> df
                    Text_1                School.2 X_Elementary_School..3                School.4 Y_Elementary_School..2
1                  Scoring                Teacher:                  Bill:                Teacher:                  John:
2            1 = Incorrect                DC Name:             X District                DC Name:             X District
3                    Text1      Date (mm/dd/yyyy):                10/7/21      Date (mm/dd/yyyy):                11/7/21
4                    Text2            Child Grade:                      K            Child Grade:                      K
5                    Text3       Student Study ID:            123-2222-2:       Student Study ID:            112-1111-3:
6                    Text4                    <NA>                   <NA>                    <NA>                   <NA>
7     Demo 1: Color Naming                    <NA>                   <NA>                       0                   <NA>
8                 Amarillo                    <NA>                   <NA>                    <NA>                   <NA>
9                     Azul                    <NA>                   <NA>                       1                   <NA>
10                   Verde                    <NA>                   <NA>                    <NA>                   <NA>
11                    Azul                    <NA>                   <NA>                    <NA>                   <NA>
12          Demo 1: Errors                       0                   <NA>                       0                   <NA>
13    Item 1: Color naming 1 = Incorrect responses         Child response 1 = Incorrect responses         Child response
14                Amarillo                       0                   <NA>                       0                   <NA>
15                    Azul                       1                   <NA>                       1                   <NA>
16                   Verde                    <NA>                   <NA>                    <NA>                   <NA>
17                    Azul                    <NA>                   <NA>                    <NA>                   <NA>
18 Item 1: Time in seconds                    <NA>                   <NA>                     120                   <NA>
19          Item 1: Errors                       0                   <NA>                       0                   <NA>
20    Item 2: Shape Naming 1 = Incorrect responses         Child response 1 = Incorrect responses         Child response
21         Cuadrado/Cuadro                       0                   <NA>                    <NA>                   <NA>
22         Cuadrado/Cuadro                    <NA>                   <NA>                       1                   <NA>
23                 Círculo                    <NA>                   <NA>                       0                   <NA>
24                Estrella                       1                   <NA>                       1                   <NA>
25                 Círculo                       1                   <NA>                    <NA>                   <NA>
26               Triángulo                       0                   <NA>                       1                   <NA>
27 Item 2: Time in seconds                    <NA>                   <NA>                     110                   <NA>
28          Item 2: Errors                       0                   <NA>                       0                   <NA>
```

Here, When the first column has encounters `Item #: Time in seconds`, I would like to keep corresponding value under `School.2` and `School.4` columns. So the first students has those `Item 1` and `Item 2` time information as empty cell so they are `NA`. The second student has those time information as `120` and `110`. These two students have two items in the example dataset.

There are multiple columns for the real dataset so I need something to be in a generalized loop.

My desired output would be:

```
> time
          id itemid time
1 123-2222-2 Item 1   NA
2 123-2222-2 Item 2   NA
3 112-1111-3 Item 1  120
4 112-1111-3 Item 2  110
```

This is my attempt but I could not add the `id` yet.

```
time.data <- df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Text_1, 'Time in seconds')) # %>%
# select(time = 4)

select_time_cols <- seq(from = 2, to = ncol(time.data), by = 2)

time <- time.data %>%
  select(time = select_time_cols)

time.t<-as.data.frame(t(time))
rownames(time.t)<-seq(1,nrow(time.t),1)
colnames(time.t)<-paste0('i',seq(1,ncol(time.t),1))
time.t<-apply(time.t,2,as.numeric)
time.t<-as.data.frame(time.t)

> time.t
  item1 item2
1    NA    NA
2   120   110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution with your test dataset, though this isn't particularly robust or elegant, so there will likely be better options out there. The key thing I did was shift the text3 row over, so that the id and time were in the same column. I put notes in the code to illuminate my steps. Hopefully this points you in the right direction or prompts those with better coding skills than my own!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2<-df%>% #Turning all to character, so that I can move the row without interfering with factor level
  mutate_all(as.character)
df2[5, 2:(ncol(df2) - 1)] <- df2[5, 3:ncol(df2)] #shifting row 5, which is the "Text3" that has studentID to be the same column as the times

df3<-df2%>%
  filter(grepl("Text3|Time in seconds", Text_1))%>% #removing unnecessary rows
  mutate(type = case_when(grepl("Text", Text_1) ~ "itemid", #Relabling the Text_1 column
                          grepl("Item 1", Text_1) ~ "1",
                          grepl("Item 2", Text_1) ~ "2"))%>%
  select(grep("type|^School", names(.))) #only keeping needed columns

colnames(df3) <- df3[1,] #Taking the first row and making it the column names
df3 <- df3[-1, ] #removing row 1, since it was made into column names


df3%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-itemid, names_to = "id", values_to = "time")%>% #Making the data into longer format
  select(id, itemid, time)%>% #relocating columns to match desired output
  arrange(desc(id)) #sorting to match desired output
```